# Equivalent to MapStruct for NestJS and Node in general

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, mapstruct

Is there an equivalent of MapStruct, the mapping library widely used in Java, but for javascript, and more precisely for typescript. I know these are two very different languages but I like a lot the annototation style used by Mapstruct to map an entity field to another field in the dto, or the way that you can ignore a field, apply some functions to it like compact a firstName and a lastName coming from the entity to a property fullName in a DTO.

Do you know a library in TS allowing me to replicate the Mapstruct behavior, or do you have some suggestions for me to build my own ?

Comment: I guess this lib could help you: https://automapperts.netlify.app/